# Keras - Merging layers - Keras 2.0

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am trying to merge two networks. I can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
merged = Merge([CNN_Model, RNN_Model], mode='concat')
```

But I get a warning:

```
merged = Merge([CNN_Model, RNN_Model], mode='concat')
__main__:1: UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
```

So I tried this:

```
merged = Concatenate([CNN_Model, RNN_Model])
model = Sequential()
model.add(merged)
```

and got this error:

```
ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.
```

Can anyone give me the syntax as how I would get this to work?

Comment: Could you provide us with a full models definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use sequential models for models with branches.

Use the Functional API:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

You're right in using the `Concatenate` layer, but you must pass "tensors" to it. And first you create it, then you call it with input tensors (that's why there are two parentheses):

```
concatOut = Concatenate()([CNN_Model.output,RNN_Model.output])
```

For creating a model out of that, you need to define the path from inputs to outputs:

```
model = Model([CNN_Model.input, RNN_Model.input], concatOut)
```

> This answer assumes your existing models have only one input and output each.

Comment: This is great, What if I wanted to add some more layers to this model? I tried this: `model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax', name='final_dense'))` and it gave me `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: Create the layer and give it the input to get the output: `denseOut = Dense(22,activation='softmax',name='final_dense')(concatOut)` --- Your model will then be like `model = Model([CNN_Model.input, RNN_Model.input], denseOut)`